# how to slow down the movement of physics objects in Corona SDKs

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to slow down the speeds of objects moving with phyics...I want them to move in the same way but to slow down there speed.I hope u understand my problem.thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do so, depending on what you want to achieve. The simplest way is to set a `linear damping` value in the body in question. See the documentation [here](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/bodylineardamping).

Another way, also quite simple, is to apply a force at every frame in the contrary direction as the object moves. You can alter the force applied by the speed the object moves in the direction. See the `applyForce` method [here.](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/bodyapplyforce)

Comment: I have tried a lot with Linear damping , Angular damping , Apply force , Set velocity etc. I just want to change the speed of the object not his motion or direction as the objects coming in much faster speed and suddenly after some collision these objects come with slow speed but with the same position or route as the gravity is fixed ... I do my best to explain my problem...

Comment: Any guidance regarding the problem ... Totally get stuck with it didn't have a lot of experience in programming

Comment: I now understand. Of course, when applying a force to an object, this will alter the route of it, since a gravitational force is also applied every frame. One thing you can try is to update the physics world with a scaled time parameter. This would slow down the movement of **all** objects in the world. But on a first glance, this doesn't seem possible with Corona.

Answer (score 0):

you change the value of gravity .That is use physics.setGravity(0,value).Adjust the speed as you want

Answer (score 0):

Use physics gravity to slow down ur object`physics.setGravity(-2,10)`
Read this website:http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/physicssetgravity